# Bluetooth manager and bluetoothctl can't find one specific bluetooth device. Working in Dual Boot with windows, which can finde the device

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have a dual boot system with windows 10 pro and Ubuntu 20.04.

Last year I got a bluetooth mouse 3600. Since every time I changed the OS I had to pair the mouse, so I tried to get the key from Ubuntu to be the same as windows' key. Since then anything in Ubuntu cannot find the mouse, but only the mouse. It can find other devices like normal.

The mouse can connect to another Laptop(Kali Linux) and Windows just fine, but the MAC address of the mouse shown in Windows is different than the MAC address that shows on Kali Linux.

I tried scanning for the bluetooth mouse via `bluetoothctl scan on`, but it didn't find the mouse at all.

I also did `show`:

```
[bluetooth]# show

Controller C8:94:02:7D:A8:6C (public)

Name: myname-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-2

    Alias: alexander-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-2
    Class: 0x007c010c
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0540
    Discovering: yes
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x08 (8)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 1M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 2M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: Coded
```

At first I thought that the key is messed up since I tried to change it, but the mouse has to be connected so that I can find the device info file, so there isn't even a key that can be messed up.